# Why is partial linking making all symbols non-global?

Tags: c++, linker, clang, ld, mach-o

I'm trying to reduce the disk size of a big static library `libIn.a` that contains a lot (~3000) of small object files (`.o`), by combining all the object files into a single `.o` file; as far as I understand, this procedure is called "partial linking". The size reduction would be achieved by collapsing all the object sections (one per `.o` file) into a single one.

The problem I'm seeing is that the procedure I'm using does not preserve global-ness of the symbols included in the `.o` files included in `libIn.a` i.e., all symbols become local after the partial linking, and that causes "undefined symbol" errors downstream in the linking process.

As an example, that's how `version.o` object file (originally included in `libIn.a`, you can download `version.o` at https://github.com/giovanniberi93/problematic_object_file) looks like *before* performing partial linking:

```bash
└─ nm -Ca version.o
0000000000000000 T webrtc::LoadWebRTCVersionInRegister()
0000000000000024 s l_.str
0000000000000000 t ltmp0
0000000000000024 s ltmp1
```

So now the symbol `webrtc::LoadWebRTCVersionInRegister()` is global (`T`).

But when performing partial linking, the same symbol becomes local (`t`):

```bash
└─ ld -r version.o -o why_is_local.o

└─ nm -Ca why_is_local.o
0000000000000024 s LC1
0000000000000000 t webrtc::LoadWebRTCVersionInRegister()
```

Things get even weirder: when trying to replicate the same scenario with a sample `.o` file, **the global symbols are not converted into local symbols (!)**; e.g., with input C++ file:

```cpp
int function1() {
    return 1;
}
```

Its global symbol `function1()` is **not** converted into local symbol by performing partial linkage i.e., it stays global (`T`) before and after partial linking:

```bash
└─ clang -c file1.cc

└─ nm -Ca file1.o
0000000000000000 T function1()
0000000000000000 t ltmp0
0000000000000008 s ltmp1

└─ ld -r file1.o -o relocated.o

└─ nm -Ca relocated.o
0000000000000000 T function1()
```

**There must be some difference in `version.o` and `file1.o` that is causing the global symbols to become local, but I've not been able to pinpoint it. Any input would be greatly appreciated.**

---

My env (MacOS 12.6, arm64):

```bash
└─ clang -v
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/giober/Desktop/XCodes/13.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

└─ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-711
BUILD 18:11:19 Aug  3 2021
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 13.0.0, (clang-1300.0.29.3) (static support for 27, runtime is 27)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 13.0.0 (tapi-1300.0.6.5)

└─ nm --version
Apple LLVM version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  Optimized build.
  Default target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
  Host CPU: vortex
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code that was used to compile version.o, and the compilation command that was used?

Answer (score 0):

The symbol in question is marked as "private external":

```
% nm -m version.o 
0000000000000000 (__TEXT,__text) private external __ZN6webrtc27LoadWebRTCVersionInRegisterEv
0000000000000024 (__TEXT,__cstring) non-external l_.str
0000000000000000 (__TEXT,__text) non-external ltmp0
0000000000000024 (__TEXT,__cstring) non-external ltmp1
```

Not sure where that's coming from, but you can preserve this state with `-keep_private_externs`:

```
ld -keep_private_externs -r version.o -o output.o
```